# "conn 0x7f7d6c001610 error: i=-2 errno=11 state=4 rc=3 br=721" Appearing in nxweb log

Tags: c, webserver, nxweb

I am writing a custom handler and wanted to see how stable it is and just let my browser request the same URL over and over. It doesn't crash but I get some messages like the one in the title.

I.e.

`conn 0x7f7d6c001610 error: i=-2 errno=11 state=4 rc=3 br=721`

This also happens when I execute the "hello" example but far less often.

Could you give me any pointers as to why this happens? Do I have to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error report is not critical. This means connection to client dropped for some reason before request has been fulfilled.

Comment: Why does this happen more often when I do request my module instead of the "hello" one? Does this point to problems in my module?

Comment: I don't think so. Perhaps your handler takes more time than hello to complete request. This increases probability of link being dropped before request completes.